# Classificar gramaticalmente uma palavra em português

Tags: python, python-3.x, módulo-python

É sabido que é possível classificar morfologicamente as palavras através do módulo nltk, porém ele funciona diretamente apenas com o inglês, sendo necessário para outros idiomas um processo complicado. Existe algum módulo ou método que possibilite classificar palavras portuguesas como substantivo, verbo, conjunção, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode olhar para este [link](https://github.com/pedrobalage/Portuguese-Natural-Language-Processing-with-Python/blob/master/book/Chapter%203%20-%20NLP%20Processing.ipynb), parece que eles estão trabalhando na documentação de `langdetect`.

Eu acho que você pode contatá-los para obter mais detalhes sobre a página [Github](https://github.com/pedrobalage/Portuguese-Natural-Language-Processing-with-Python/blob/master/book/Chapter%200%20-%20Preface.ipynb).

Existe também a biblioteca [`polyglot`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polyglot). O Polyglot é um canal de linguagem natural que suporta aplicações multilíngues maciças.